# Setting up port forwarding on router for reverse SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

My home PC is behind NAT but my router has static ip address. My work PC uses 3G stick for Internet (So I guess it is like being behind NAT).

I would like to create a reverse SSH-tunnel to connect to my work PC. Following lots of manuals I create a tunnel on my work PC:

```
ssh -R 33333:localhost:22 homeuser@135.142.205.131
```

Where `135.142.205.131` is my router's static IP address.
When trying to connect to work from home I isssue:

```
ssh -p 33333 localhost
```

But I get "connection refused". I think I need to configure some port forwarding because I think I need to somehow make ssh let me connect some local port to my router's 33333 port to make the tunnel work.
How do I do it?

Output at my work PC:

```
netstat -nap --inet --tcp

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56789           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1402/klient
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 10.0.85.14:56731        104.20.90.217:443       ESTABLISHED 1402/klient
tcp        0      1 10.0.85.14:52501        135.142.205.131:22      SYN_SENT    2366/ssh
tcp        0      0 10.0.85.14:56789        52.49.10.125:53633      ESTABLISHED 1402/klient
tcp        0      0 10.0.85.14:47118        104.20.89.217:443       ESTABLISHED 1402/klient
```

Output of `netstat - output` at my works PC:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 10.0.85.14:56731        104.20.90.217:https     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 10.0.85.14:52501        135.142.205.131:ssh     SYN_SENT
tcp        0      0 10.0.85.14:56789        ec2-52-49-10-125.:53633 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.85.14:47118        104.20.89.217:https     ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: If your router forwards port 33333 to the pc-port 22, you should be able to connect directly via ssh -p 3333 homeuser@....

Comment: I'm not quite understanding you. I though I forward my home PC's port 33333 to my work's 22. So why should I connect to port 22 on home's PC?

Comment: Sorry, i did misunderstand, see my edited comment above

Comment: @gerhardd. why do I need "homeuser@..." ? "homeuser" is me on my home's PC, where I try to connect to work, do I need it? Did you mean homeuser@localhost?

Comment: Ah, sorry2. You may give me a downvote for not reading tightly.. :( The reverse tunnel seems to be okay. You may verify this with "netstat -nap --inet --tcp", and look at the open connections at your work pc. As a second step, you need to make shure the ssh-daemon is listening on the work pc at localhost:22. This is also visible in the netstat - output. Please post it here, so we may look at it.

Comment: @gerhardd. Do I also need to set up port forwarding on my router from port 33333 on router to some port on home PC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38529/discussion-between-gerhard-d-and-rightaway717).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
 tcp 0 1 10.0.85.14:52501 135.142.205.131:22 SYN_SENT 2366/ssh
```

tells us, that the ssh-connection from the work pc to the home-pc has not been completed. So either
a) the port forwarding from the router to the home-pc does not work, or
b) the ssh-d on the home pc is not listening to the (correct) address

Comment: Ssh connection didn't really complete, as port forwarding was not correct on router. For simplicity I created 22 to 22 port forwarding on router as @gerhard suggested and it did work. Thank you @gerhard!